# Flask-Admin with mongoengine - how to set a “persistent filter” on a view?

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-admin

I try to use Flask-Admin with Mongoengine and I am totally stuck. I can’t find a solution to implement a “persistent filter”. What I mean by that is, a user should only see and interact with items in a view (list), that are resulting from a custom query in mongoengine.

If I have a model

```
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    days = DecimalField()
    book = StringField()
```

and I want to show in the first view only books depending on a specific user, I would do a query:

```
user_peter = User.objects(name=’Peter’)
```

and if I want to show overdue books for Peter, I would do a query:

```
overdue_books = User.objects(name=’Peter’, days__gt=28)
```

how can I implement that in a custom flask-admin-view? What do I have to set in the ModelView?

```
Class LentBooks(ModelView):
    menu_class_name=”Your Books”
    #???

Class OverdueBooks(ModelView):
    menu_class_name=”Overdue Books”
    #???
```

or do I have to put it here?

```
Admin.add_view(LentBooks(model=User, #???))
```

For SQLAlchemy, there are many recipes, but not for mongoengine. Please help!

What I have found, is in flask_admin.contrib.mongoengine.filters

```
class FilterEqual(BaseMongoEngineFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value):
        flt = {'%s' % self.column.name: value}
        return query.filter(**flt)

    def operation(self):
        return lazy_gettext('equals')
```

But how to implement this??

**THANK YOU pjcunningham!!**

Here is the solution from **pjcunningham** in a small test-source:

```
from flask import Flask
import flask_admin as admin
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_admin.contrib.mongoengine import ModelView

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '1234567890'
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'db': 'library'}

db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)

class User(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    days = db.DecimalField()
    book = db.StringField()

class OverdueBooks(ModelView):
    def get_query(self):
        overdue_books = User.objects(name='Peter', days__gt=28)
        return overdue_books

if __name__ == '__main__':

    admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example: Library')

    admin.add_view(OverdueBooks(model=User, name='Library'))

    app.run(debug=True)
```

in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5815f403e198515188860e3c"), "name" : "Jane", "days" : 21, "book" : "Testbook1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5815f416e198515188860e3d"), "name" : "Peter", "days" : 30, "book" : "Testbook2" }
```

**Thank you very much! It works!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `get_query` in your view. e.g.

```
class OverdueBooks(ModelView):

    def get_query(self):            
        overdue_books = User.objects(name=’Peter’, days__gt=28)
        return overdue_books
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
May I ask you, where can I find more about the topic "filter with queries"?

Comment: @Henrich Schlegal - I found a brief note in the source for the [SQLAlchemy view](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.get_query). There's a similar note for the mongoengine excepty you don't have to override `get_count_query`.

Comment: Every example is about SQLAlchemy! And there is only one book about Mongoengine on Amazon and that is in Portuguese! It is very hard to learn mongoengine. Thanks again!

Comment: @HeinrichSchlegel [Quokka CMS](https://github.com/quokkaproject/quokka) is a good place to start learning Flask/MongoDB/Flask-Admin if you don't mind reading through source code. I learnt a lot from this project even though I mostly use SQLAlchemy with Flask.